# Rails - Active Record: add extra select column to find(:all)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want to add new column `sum(time_entries.hours)` to sql select 
I'm querying entries like this:

```
issues = Issue.visible.where(options[:conditions]).all(
    :include => ([:status, :project, :time_entries] + (options[:include] || [])).uniq,
    :conditions => statement,
    :order => order_option,
    :joins => query_joins(order_option.join(',')),
    :limit => options[:limit],
    :offset => options[:offset],
    :group => "#{Issue.table_name}.id"
)
```

It generates this select:

```
SELECT
 "issues"."id"                         AS t0_r0,
 ...
 "time_entries"."hours"                AS t3_r4,
 ...
 "versions"."sharing"                  AS t8_r9
FROM "issues"
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."id" = "issues"."project_id"
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "issue_statuses" ON "issue_statuses"."id" = "issues"."status_id"
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "time_entries" ON "time_entries"."issue_id" = "issues"."id"
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "issues"."assigned_to_id"
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "trackers" ON "trackers"."id" = "issues"."tracker_id"
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "enumerations"
   ON "enumerations"."id" = "issues"."priority_id" AND "enumerations"."type" IN ('IssuePriority')
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "issue_categories" ON "issue_categories"."id" = "issues"."category_id"
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "versions" ON "versions"."id" = "issues"."fixed_version_id"
WHERE "issues"."id" IN (1) AND (projects.status <> 9 AND projects.id IN (SELECT
                                                                       em.project_id
                                                                     FROM enabled_modules em
                                                                     WHERE em.name =     'issue_tracking')) AND
  ((issues.status_id IN (SELECT
                           id
                         FROM issue_statuses
                         WHERE is_closed = 'f')))
GROUP BY issues.id
ORDER BY issues.id
 DESC
```

I tried insert `:select=>"*, sum(time_entries.hours)"` into hash parameter to `all` method, but there is no effect.

How can I add new column to this select? 
Also I need preserve all current columns, since they are used in filters.
Is there any way without specifying all columns by hands?

**UPDATE:**
Ruby 1.9.3
Rails 3.2.13

Comment: In your first code block, why are you mixing new `arel` query methods (`where`) with old deprecated magic finders?  `.all(:include => [...])`?  You should change it all to use `arel` as your `.all` method is going to stop working when you upgrade rails.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I will fix it. This is part of plugin to redmine - I'm overriding controller action - this part is copy-paste from overridden action(with some minor modifications).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The table names look like from Redmine. I actually ran into a similar problem recently. What I found was that the selected colums stem from the visible scope. I could not pin down why exactly but working without it, the 'select' option worked as intended.

Using

```
Issue.select("#{Issue.table_name}.*, sum(#{TimeEntries.table_name}.hours AS total_hours").where("#{your_conditions}").group(:id).all
```

should give you the data you want. The additional column can be accessed directly as an Issue attribute:

```
Issue.total_hours
```

**Edit:**

If it's not possible to select all Issue fields (for creating the full Issue objects) and the sum at the same time, you need to use a second statement after getting the issues you want.

```
issues = Issue.visible.where("#{issue_conditions}").all
issue_ids = issues.map(&:id)
# if you do not need the issue objects, use .pluck(:id) instead of .all

spent_hours = TimeEntries.select('issue_id, sum(hours)')
                         .where(:issue_id => issue_ids)
                         .where("#{other_time_conditions}")
                         .group(:issue_id).all
```

---

Alternatively you can use the included convenience functions in Redmines Issue class. Use this to make the Software do the work for you:

```
i = Issue.includes(:time_entries).find(1)
i.total_spent_hours
```

The include makes sure that the calculation doesn't hit the database a second time because all related associations are already loaded.

Comment: Yes, you are right - this is part of plugin for redmine. In first example you mean replacing `all(...)` to `select(..)` or prepend this select to `all`?
Second variant doesn't suits me at all since I want use filters on timeentries records in my query(to calculate spent time in_between for example)

Comment: I've made the example more specific, just leaving out your includes, limits and other special conditions. Like the comment on your original post stated, you should rather use AREL methods to build your statement instead of dumping it into the `.all` method. Also, I added another alternative which uses two selects. Sometimes it's easier and often even faster to use more selects instead of one big select with many joins.

Comment: Thanks, first variant is exactly what I need.

Comment: It is definitely possible to have both in one query, you need grouping!

Answer (score 5):

Bit old but something like this should work. (In Rails 5 ish)

```
issues = Issue. ...

issues.select(
  issues.arel.projections,
  TimeEntry.arel_table[:hours].sum
)
```