# Rails scope using instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

You have a model `Store` with an attribute `time_zone`(New York, London, Tokyo, etc.).

All stores are open from 8am to 9pm in their local time zone.

You have an instance method to check if the store is currently open:

```
def currently_open?
  current_store_time = Time.now.in_time_zone(time_zone)
  (8...21).cover? current_store_time.hour
end
```

**How do you create a rails scope for all currently open stores using the `Store#currently_open?` instance method (or without that method, but I want to use the rails `scope` syntax).**

`scope :currently_open, -> { "use Store#currently_open? here" }`

Comment: heading seems like -> Rails class method using instance method. I guess you misunderstood basics.

Comment: What's the data type of `time_zone`, what RDMBS are you using (if any)?

Comment: BTW, `(8..21).cover? current_store_time` will always return `false`. You have to compare against `current_store_time.hour` and you probably want `8...21` (triple dot), i.e. up to but not including 21. (unless the stores are open until 9:59pm)

Comment: You are right! Thanks Stefan

Answer (score 3):

Does this works for you?

```rb
scope :with_current_store_time, -> {
  select(all.arel.projections, "date_part('hour', NOW() at time zone time_zone) as current_store_time")
}
scope :currently_open, -> {
  with_current_store_time.where(current_store_time: 8..21)
}
```

Basically I rewrote `current_store_time` as a scope (`with_current_store_time`)

I answered this using these as references:

- [How to return current date in a different timezone in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017058/how-to-return-current-date-in-a-different-timezone-in-postgresql)
- [Convert a UTC timezone in postgresql to EST (local time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36341060/convert-a-utc-timezone-in-postgresql-to-est-local-time/36341459)
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC
- [Rails - Active Record: add extra select column to find(:all)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750196/rails-active-record-add-extra-select-column-to-findall)

Notes :

1. `current_store_time` probably not describing the actual value being calculated.
2. `current_store_time` is returning hour, on the specified timezone.

Answer (score 1):

If your table only contains a `time_zone` string which contains a valid Rails time zone name (or alias), you'll have to somehow generate a list of time zone names that are currently between 8 am and 9 pm.

To do so, you could write a helper method that fetches the used time zones in your table via `Store.distinct.pluck(:time_zone)` and selects those that match the criteria:

```
class Store
  def self.time_zones_between(hours)
    distinct.pluck(:time_zone).select do |time_zone|
      Time.use_zone(time_zone) { hours.cover?(Time.current.hour) }
    end
  end

  scope :currently_open, -> { where(time_zone: time_zones_between(8...21) }
end
```

Note that calling `Store.currently_open` will result two queries: one to get the time zones and one to fetch the actual results. You can avoid the first query by providing the list of available time zones yourself.